# How to dynamically create extra fields to all annotated models through hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, code-injection

I have a set of POJO classes with its hibernate xml definitions. I'm now trying to add two new fields 'createdDate' and 'createdBy' for all those models. I don't want to add them manually to all my POJOs and xml as they are huge in number.

Is it possible to create these fields dynamically through hibernate?

**Sample POJO1**

```
@BasePOJO
public class MyPOJO1 {

private String name;
private int age;
// Setter and Getter Methods
}
```

**Hibernate XML for POJO1**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="MyPOJO1">
   <property column="name" length="50" name="name" type="string"/>
   <property column="age" length="50" name="age" type="integer"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**What to be done**

```
// TODO: Get all POJO annotated with BasePOJO 
// TODO: Dynamically create the required fields
```

**The other possible solutions i ignore**

- Adding those extra fields in a separate class and extending them in all my POJOs and Making all my hbm xml definitions from class to subclass extending the base class

Intention is to make the effort simple and leaving a space for more common fields of this sort to come in future. Thanks for any guidance in this regard.

Comment: Are you able to use the @ Entity and @ Table annotations instead of defining the mapping manually?

Comment: @jhell Its a legacy system that uses xml mappings and not annotations.

Comment: Have you tried the jboss tools plugin for eclipse? It looks like it can generate the mapping file from a pojo: https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/hibernate.html.

Comment: Thanks @jhell. hbm xml generation will only simplifies the work and still the new fields have to be manually added to all the classes. And we will have no way to ensure that future classes do the same. Looking for a frameworkish way ;)